# Как автоматизировать процесс в Photoshop с помощью Python на Windows

Tags: python, photoshop

На изображении две картинки соединены в одну с небольшим смещением и прозрачностью в ручную в Photoshop. Как автоматизировать этот процесс с помощью **photoshop-python-api** или **win32com.client** на Windows?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Pillow` библиотека вам должна помочь

Comment: А чем встроенные в фотошопе «Сценарии» не угодили?

Comment: Ну и да, такую элементарную задачу как наложение с прозрачностью можно сделать вообще без фотошопа